# Material Dialog returning multiple objects

Tags: javascript, html, material-design, material-ui

I am using Material Dialog to confirm "remove row" in a table .
First time remove from dialog is fine to delete a row . But after dialog.close(); and when I call the second times, it executes twice on a single click. And on third times call to dialog and click remove, it executes 3 times including the recent executions.

```
dialog.querySelector('.count').addEventListener('click', function() {
```

Please help to execute a only one function call on this dialog click event. Thank you.

```js
var count = 0;
var dialog = document.getElementById('dialog1');

function showdialog() {
  dialog.showModal();
  dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
    dialog.close();
  });
  dialog.querySelector('.count').addEventListener('click', function() {
    count += 1;
    dialog.close();
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Result Clicked on Count+1 = " + count;
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id='result'>Result = 0</div>
  <button id="show-dialog" type="button" class="mdl-button" onclick='showdialog()'>Show Dialog</button>
  <dialog class="mdl-dialog" id='dialog1'>
    <h4 class="mdl-dialog__title">Allow data collection?</h4>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
      <p>
        Allowing us to collect data will let us get you the information you want faster.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
      <button type="button" class="mdl-button count">Count +1</button>
      <button type="button" class="mdl-button close">Close</button>
    </div>
  </dialog>
</body>
```

Comment: Your snippet is not working

Comment: @SapuSeven,  It does.

Comment: It shows:
`Error: {
  "message": "TypeError: dialog.showModal is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 36,
  "colno": 3
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you has been adding new click event listener each time upon calling showDialog ( click on the show dialog button) and each event listener increment count value, that leads to such incrementing  (1, 3, 6, 10, 15 - The actual incrementing show you how much event listeners `.count` has).

Moving out `addEventListener` for the .count element in the showDialog will fix the problem, see code below:

```js
var count = 0;
var dialog = document.getElementById('dialog1');
dialog.querySelector('.count').addEventListener('click', function() {
    count += 1;
    dialog.close();
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Result Clicked on Count+1 = " + count;
  });
function showdialog() {
  dialog.showModal();
  dialog.querySelector('.close').addEventListener('click', function() {
    dialog.close();
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id='result'>Result = 0</div>
  <button id="show-dialog" type="button" class="mdl-button" onclick='showdialog()'>Show Dialog</button>
  <dialog class="mdl-dialog" id='dialog1'>
    <h4 class="mdl-dialog__title">Allow data collection?</h4>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
      <p>
        Allowing us to collect data will let us get you the information you want faster.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
      <button type="button" class="mdl-button count">Count +1</button>
      <button type="button" class="mdl-button close">Close</button>
    </div>
  </dialog>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is enough answer for solution. But may I know how to select buttons when dialog and events are created dynamically in showdialog() function.

Comment: What do you menu by `select buttons`  ?